# How can I place texture images to each side of a box in POV Ray?

Tags: textures, povray

I want to create a simple cube in pov ray and I want to place different texture images on each side of the cube.

I can find examples how to place a single image to a cube or sphere, but I haven't found anything about my issue.

Do I have to use tiles or transformations? Please enlighten me